# Cannot upload songs to my iphone 4 running ios 5.1.1 on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, rhythmbox, iphone

Using either Rhythmbox or Banshee I can move music from my iphone to my computer but I cannot move music from my computer to my iphone. If I drag a track to the phone it shows the progress bar and tells me it has uploaded but when I go into my phone the song is not there. I am running ios 5.1.1

Comment: I'm on a iPad 1 running the same iOS 5.1.1 and I can confirm the problem.